# Calling MVC Controller Action using Html button

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC.I have a button "Create". I want to create another button which calls the "Deploy" Action in my controller. This button basically Submits the form and gets deployed. Currently, the form gets submitted but the code does not enter the "Deploy" function

Here is what I have tried:-

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create and deploy" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Deploy", "MyController")' "/>
```

My Deploy function need a parameter something like this:-

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Deploy", new {Id = Model.Id })">Deploy</a>
```

**EDIT**

THis is how my code looks now:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { data_bind = "submit: formSubmit" }))
{
  <input type="submit" name ="create" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
  <input type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create and deploy"/>
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel entity, string submitType)
{
  if (submitType == Create and Deploy)
  {
    RedirectToAction("Deploy", "MyController");
  }
  //Code to create
}

public ActionResult Deploy(string Id)
{
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: change `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"`

Comment: Or you want your button to perform multiple action method, first to submit the form and then deploy, is that what you want?

Comment: @MokshShah Yes I want both the Actions

Comment: You can give the buttons a name (say `name=submittype")`, check if the posted value is "Create and deploy" and if so `RedirectToAction("Deploy", "MyController");` (there is no point having the `onclick` attribute)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate your answer ?

Comment: `submit` buttons post back their value if you give them a `name` attribute, so add a parameter to your `Create()` POST method, `string submittype` which you can then check the value (it will be either "Create" or "Create and Deploy"). You haven't posted your controller methods so hard to give you a specific answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did it. Still gives me the same output. I have edited my Question where I also need to pass a parameter to the Deploy function. I guess it does not work Because Iam not passing it. Can you help me with that

Comment: Now I'm confused. You indicated in you comments that you want to submit the form using either the `Create` button or the `Create and Deploy` button. Assuming you have a method `public ActionResult Create(yourModel model)` then add another parameter as I indicated above. You can then check the value of the button and take whatever course of action you want, e.g. redirect to the `Deploy` method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for the confusion, I have placed my edits in the question. Can you check now? I am getting the submitType =null

Comment: You need to change either the `name` attribute of the button, or the parameter name - they must match (currently when you post back `submitType` will be `null`)

Comment: Your also not passing any parameter to you `Deploy` method.

Comment: I'm not an ASP expert, but I see that your button action is also wrong. Change `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Deploy", "MyController")';"` to `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(\"Deploy\", \"MyController\")';"` Note: you may want to open your developer tools to get additional errors.

Comment: @GuyT, No. `@Url.Action("Deploy", "MyController")` is correct (but its not needed anyway)

Comment: @StephenMuecke but not with the `onclick=""` in front of it. Because he is using double quotes at that point he has to escape the strings with a backslash.

Comment: @GuyT, No, Razor code (the `@Url.Action(..` bit is parsed on the server before its passed to the view so it will render `href="/MyController/Deploy"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I now get the submitType . But it still does not go into the Deploy function. Can you please post an answer. Sorry Iam confused

Comment: Does `Arkin.BI.Resources.FrontEndLabels.CreateAndDeploy` return exactly the text "Create and deploy"? If you are going to use a constant in the POST method, you should also be using that to render the buttons `value` attribute in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes that was a typo. I have changed it now. It does not go to the Deploy function still

Comment: So what is the value of parameter `submitType` when you post the form?

Comment: I assume your latest edit is also a typo - it should be `if (submitType == "Create and deploy") {`, but since you just immediately redirect, what is the point of doing a submit - why not just call the method with `@Html.ActionLink("Deploy", "Guage", new { Id = Model.ID })`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to do the submit and the deploy. WIth @Html.ActionLink("Deploy", "Guage", new { Id = Model.ID }) wouldnt it just deploy?

Comment: Yes, But you are not doing anything in the POST method if you click the `Create and deploy` button - you immediately redirect, which is the same thing as using a link. Perhaps you mean you want to save the `GaugeConfig` data first, and then redirect to `Deploy` (or if its the other button, redirect to another method). It's still not clear what your trying do do from the code you have shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke See basically I have two buttons 1)Create 2) Create and deploy. On Create the form should only submit and not deploy. WIth Create and deploy the Form should submit and also deploy.

Comment: Then the code to save has to be placed before the `if (submitType = "..")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Works now. Thank you for the help. Can you please post an answer so that I can mark it accepted

Comment: Give me an hour or so, but if `MyModel` that you post back contains a proeprty (say) `string Id` and you want to pass that to `Deploy()` then its `RedirectToAction("Deploy", "MyController", new { Id = entity.Id })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your time buddy. I managed to solve it. Please post your answer for Adding the name attribute and REturnToAction(). I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of submit button will post back if you give it a `name` attribute. Change the html for the buttons to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitType" value="Create" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitType" value="Create and deploy" />
```

and the controller method to

```
public ActionResult Create(MyModel entity, string submitType)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(entity);
  }
  // Save the model
  ....
  // Check which button submitted the form
  if(submitType == "Create")
  {
    // redirect somewhere ?
  }
  else
  {
    // assuming you want to pass the value of entity.Id to the Deploy() method
    RedirectToAction("Deploy", "MyController", new { Id = entity.Id });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this way to hit to that deploy Action

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Deploy", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create and deploy"/>
                }
```

Comment: I already have it specified as :-  ` @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Mycontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { data_bind = "submit: formSubmit" }))`

Should I change it?

Comment: This answer assumes you want to go to the `Deploy` method whichever button you click (which I don't think you want)

Comment: you have to add separate " @using (Html.BeginForm ......"to both create and Deploye otherwise it will hit only for the create.

Comment: first way no need to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Deploy", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create and deploy"/>
                }


 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                <input type="submit" name ="create" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
                }
```

Or you need to change the action of form on click of the button like

```
function deploybtnClick{
document.getElementById('formId').action = 'Deploy';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Deploy", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
            {
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create and deploy"/>
            }

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
            {
            <input type="submit" name ="create" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each button add an client side function.

Function will have ajax call, and you can set the Url Property with your required ActionName and ControllerName